# Object.create() ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Can you help me to understand ES6 and Object ?

```
class Contact{
       constructor(name,tel,mail)
       this.name=name;
       this.tel=tel;
       this.mail=mail; 

    method1(){
    //code
   }
}
```

If I want create a contact I can use

```
const me = new Contact('David','070809112','10 street of Paris')
```

But I'm not able to use **Object.create()** before ES6 I can use Object.create() with ES6 Ican't can you help me ?

### **BEFORE ES6**

```
var Contact ={
   init:function('name','tel','mail')
   this.name=name;
   this.tel=tel;
   this.mail=mail; 

method1 : function(){
  //code
 }
}
 var me = Object.create(Contact);
 me.init('David','070809112','10 street of Paris');
```

In this case How use Object.create() ? for create a new contact. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do `Object.create(Contact)` in ES6 where `Contact` is defined as a class?

Comment: The comparison you make is broken: your last code example has no constructor, but an `init` method which is called separately: this you can also do with ES6 `class` and `Object.create`. The thing is that you introduce a `constructor` in the ES6 example, which for some reason you did not choose to use in the ES5 code. So the comparison really does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep doing exactly what you were doing and not use `class`.

If you're using `class`, you typically don't use `Object.create`. The use cases for `Object.create` are largely unrelated to `class` (it's usually used in direct prototypical inheritance, rather than using constructor functions).

If you want to use `class` but don't want to use `new` for some reason, you can use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) (rather than `Object.create`):

```js
class Contact {
    constructor(name, tel, mail) {
        this.name=name;
        this.tel=tel;
        this.mail=mail; 
    }
    method1(){
     //code
    }
}

const c = Reflect.construct(Contact, ["name", "tel", "mail"]);
console.log(c.name);
```

It *is* possible to use `Object.create` with your `class Contact`, like this:

```
// NOT A GOOD IDEA, see below
const c = Object.create(Contact.prototype);
```

That creates an object using `Contact.prototype` as its prototype. But it doesn't call the constructor, and you can't call the constructor afterward (`Contact.call(c, "name", "tel", "email")` would fail). And you couldn't be sure that not calling the constructor didn't cause a problem, since `class` code assumes the constructor (and super constructors if any) are called.

Comment: I understand with class Ican't use Object.create() in this case thanks

Comment: @Parad0xJ - Well, you **can**: `const c = Object.create(Contact.prototype);` will create an object using the prototype from `Contact`. But it doesn't run the constructor and you can't run it separately (doing `Contact.call(c, "name", "tel", "mail")` would fail).

Comment: T.J.Crowder thanks for all your explanations I understand well my mistake

Comment: I have a class Foo that inherits from `HTMLElement`. In order to avoid `illegal constructor` issues with `new Foo()` ( same for `Reflect.construct(Foo,[])` ) I use Object.create(Foo.prototype). => With ES6 classes there is still a (limited) use case for Object.create. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478484/how-to-test-custom-web-component-with-jest/

Answer (score 0):

T.J Crowder answer is the best thing i have ever seen. yeap  Reflect.construct() works as expected this has saved my day of hours searching because i had a problem i wanted to call a function with an instance together with other variables off the back in laravel blade, however adding a space in between made the dumb thing break so i could not use the new keyword. javascript flexibility saved the day. Learnt a totally new thing and thank you for being oblivious of why one would not want to use new keyword and focusing on answering the question. i wish i could comment on his answer but low rep.

i had this
`onclick={{$var1.".method( new MyClass(this.id,'".$var2."','".$var3."') )"}}`

another reason i at times hate templating engines, they can be limiting